# Can anyone suggest how to generate Rest body dynamically while calling Get API with Query match

Tags: c#, web-api-testing

In my case, while calling API (GET Method), I should send the below query as part of the body.

```
URI : GET XXX/_search

Body:
{
  "query": 
   {
    "match_all": 
      {
      }
   }
}
```

As of now, I'm hard-coding the string and appending to the resource body.

Comment: have you getting response

Comment: Yes im getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hopefully below code snippet can help you.
**Consumer:**

```
        JsonField jsn1 = new JsonField() { Name = "_id"};
        jsn1.AddValue("1234");

        JsonField jsn2 = new JsonField() { Name = "_name" };
        jsn2.AddValue("CDE");

        JsonField jsn0 = new JsonField(true) { Name = "match" };
        JsonField jsn = new JsonField(true) { Name = "query" };


        JsonConverter.MapField(jsn0, jsn1);
        JsonConverter.MapField(jsn, jsn0);

        JsonConverter jsonconverter = new JsonConverter();
        jsonconverter.Add(jsn);

        JsonField jsn3 = new JsonField() { Name = "name" };
        jsn3.AddValue("temp");
        jsonconverter.Add(jsn3);

        Console.WriteLine(jsonconverter.GetJsonFormat());
```

**Check logic below.**

```
public class JsonConverter
{
    LinkedList<JsonField> jsonlinking = new LinkedList<JsonField>();

    public void Add(JsonField jsonfield)
    {
        LinkedListNode<JsonField> jsonelement = jsonlinking.Last;
        if (jsonelement != null)
        {
            jsonelement.Value.SpecialChar = ",";
        }
        jsonlinking.AddLast(jsonfield);
    }

    public string GetJsonFormat()
    {
        jsonformat = string.Empty;
        jsonformat += "{" + Environment.NewLine;

        foreach (var item in jsonlinking)
        {
            ReadJson(item);
        }

        jsonformat += Environment.NewLine + "}" + Environment.NewLine;

        return jsonformat;
    }

    public static void MapField(JsonField primary, JsonField relative)
    {
        primary.Next = relative;
    }

    public static void MapField(Queue<JsonField> linksource)
    {
        JsonField primary = null;
        JsonField relative = null;
        foreach (var item in linksource)
        {
            if (primary == null)
            {
                primary = item;
            }
            else if (relative == null)
            {
                relative = null;
            }
            else
            {
                JsonConverter.MapField(primary, relative);
                primary = null;
                relative = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private string jsonformat = string.Empty;
    private void ReadJson(JsonField field)
    {
        if (field != null)
        {
            jsonformat += @"""";
            jsonformat += field.Name;
            jsonformat += @"""";
            if (field.isContainer)
            {
                jsonformat += @":{" + Environment.NewLine;
                int count = field.ChildNodes.Count();
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in field.ChildNodes)
                    {

                        ReadJson(item); 
                    }
                }
                jsonformat = (jsonformat.Substring(jsonformat.Length - 1, 1) == ",") ? jsonformat.Substring(0, jsonformat.Length - 1) : jsonformat;
                jsonformat += @"}" + field.SpecialChar + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            else
            {
                jsonformat += @":";
                jsonformat += field.GetValues();
            }
        }
    }

}

public class JsonField
{
    private int Size = 1;
    private int CurrentIndex = 0;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    private string[] _value;
    public string[] Value { get { return _value; } private set { _value = value; } }

    public bool isContainer{get;set;}

    public JsonField()
    {
        this.Value = new string[this.Size];
    }

    private Queue<JsonField> _next = new Queue<JsonField>();
    public JsonField Next { 
        set 
        {
            if (this._next.Count>0)
            {
                foreach (var item in this._next)
                {
                    item.SpecialChar = ",";
                }

            }
            this._next.Enqueue(value); 
        } 
    }

    public IEnumerable<JsonField> ChildNodes { get { return this._next; } }

    public JsonField(int valuesize)
    {
        this.Size = valuesize;
        this.Value = new string[this.Size];
    }

    public JsonField(bool iscontainer)
    {
        this.isContainer = iscontainer;
    }

    public void AddValue(string value)
    {
        if (CurrentIndex >= this.Value.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Index Out of Range over Value Array");
            return;
        }
        this.Value[CurrentIndex] = value;
        CurrentIndex++;
    }

    public void ClearValue()
    {
        this.Value = null;
        this.Value = new string[this.Size];
    }

    public string GetValues()
    {
        if (this.Value.Length == 1)
        {
            return @"""" + this.Value[0] + @"""";
        }
        string returns=string.Empty;
        for (int index = 0; index < this.Value.Length; index++)
        {
            returns += @"""" + this.Value[index] + @"""";
            if ((index +1) < this.Value.Length)
            {
                returns += ",";
            }
        }
        return "[" + returns+ "]";
    }

    public string SpecialChar { get; set; }
}
```